# SQL Server 2008 installation error: Previous releases of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, installation

I got this weird error which mentions I should install VSTS 2008 SP1, during the process of installation of SQL Server 2008 developer edition. But actually I have VSTS 2008 SP1 installed. Any ideas what is wrong?

Here is my screen snapshot.

http://i41.tinypic.com/9teo7m.jpg

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956139) for that error. Here's another [interesting article](http://blogs.msdn.com/psssql/archive/2008/08/11/sql-server-2008-visual-studio-2008-sp1-and-net-framework-3-5-sp1-explained.aspx).

If you have multiple Visual Studio products installed, you must upgrade all of them to SP1. If you have Visual Studio 2008 and one or more 2008 Express Editions, you cannot upgrade the Express Editions until you have upgraded Visual Studio.

If you have not installed Visual Studio 2008 RTM but have this problem it is because Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) is installed on your system but not at the SP1 level. This is probably because it was left over from a SQL Server 2008 CTP installation.

Did you doublecheck if you have SP1 in the About box?  The service pack should be in the list of "Installed products".

Comment: I am confused about "Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode)", it is a required component or not during our development? If I uninstall it, I am not sure whether it will have any impact...

Comment: It would seem to be a leftover from a CTP version of SQL Server 2008.  Try to remove it?  In the worst case, you'd have to reinstall SQL Server.

Comment: I have tried to remove "Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode)", and it works, cool! My last question is, what is "Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode)"? Do we need to use it or not? (I want to use SQL Server 2008, but do not want to lose any existing functions.)

Comment: The Shell seems to be a way to develop a Visual Studio versions for your own languages http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb510103.aspx  Seems unlikely you'll need it:)

Comment: "for your own languages" -- confused. Could you say in some other words please (sorry for my bad English)? I use C#/VB/C++/C. :-)

Comment: IT would be useful to develop a new language, like George2++, or George2Script.

Comment: @Andomar, I read Visual Studio 2008 Shell in some more details, looks like it is some interface/framework to allow tools to integrate with VSTS IDE. I agree 3rd party tools like Iron Python could use VSTS Shell, but does any Microsoft tools (like databse designer and other tools in VSTS) dependent on VSTS Shell?

Comment: My guess is it's a leftover from the CTP install and nobody's using it. It can't even be upgraded to SP1.

Comment: @Andomar, yes it is weird. Anyway, I think my question is answered. I will start a new thread to discuss Shell. I start a new thread here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845152/what-is-visual-studio-2008-shell-integrated-mode you are appreciated to join if you like. :-)

Comment: I've run into the same problem. Uninstalling the VS2008 Shell thingy fixed the problem. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6):

renaming the following registry key during install of SQL 2008

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\9.0

Comment: If you are using a 64 bit machine, come to this page, and this doesn't fix.. rename THIS key: `\Software\**WOW6432Node**\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\9.0\`

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/baf09c3f-be97-4bc8-b6d7-bdeea2e3719e/sql-server-2008-r2-management-studio-install-fails-telling-me-to-install-visual-studio-2008-sp1?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) is used by Team Explorer (client to Team Foundation Server) as well as SQL management tools.

If you install Team Explorer AFTER you install Visual Studio 2008 SP1 then Team Explorer will regress some of the VS Shell files to the RTM patch level even though Visual Studio itself is at SP1.

Rerunning the Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack installer should patch up the files that the Team Explorer install regressed, no need to uninstall the Shell.

See this [detailed description](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2009/04/23/installation-order-for-visual-studio-2008-sp1-team-explorer-and-sql-server-2008.aspx).

To paraphrase, the install order is important and should be as follows:

1. Visual Studio 2008
2. Team Explorer
3. Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1
4. SQL Server