# what is Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, shell

I am new to Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode), I just want to know what is its function? (I did not find much clearly from the web.)

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb510103.aspx
looks like it is some interface/framework to allow tools to integrate with VSTS IDE. My question is whether any Microsoft VSTS tools (like databse designer and other tools in VSTS) dependent on VSTS Shell? I am asking this question because it is conflicting with SQL Server 2008, and I want to make sure that if I uninstaill VSTS Shell, it does not impact anything.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 7):

SQL Server 2008 Management Studio using the VS 2008 Shell. (That's why it looks and feels just like Visual Studio).

Comment: But VSTS Shell conflicts with SQL Server 2008. I do not know why. Please refer to here and after uninstall VSTS Shell, SQL Server 2008 could be installed successfully.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844945/sql-server-2008-installation-error

BTW: after uninstall VSTS shell, then install SQL Server 2008, then I find SQL Server 2008 management service could be used normally, in your words, SQL Server 2008 management service should not be able to use since I uninstall it in first step.

Any ideas or comments?

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio Shell is an extensibility mechanism provided to use Visual Studio core platform to provide your own tools. It has two modes. In "Isolated Mode," it'll always set up a separate instance of Visual Studio that hosts your tool. In "Integrated Mode," it'll only install a new VS instance if there's no one already available. If one is already there, it'll integrate with it. I don't think removing it causes any problems for a VS installation. It seems to be smart enough to handle it (it might break a third party tool, however).

Comment: Besides non-Microsoft tools, are there any Microsoft product tools dependent on VSTS Shell?

Comment: I'm not sure. SQL Server Management Studio is certainly based on VS code base but I doubt it depends on "VS Shell Integrated Mode" as a separate feature. Having installed VS2008 and SQL2008 I don't see such a program in Programs and Features control panel.

Comment: 1. " I don't see such a program" -- you mean VSTS Shell Integrated Mode?

2. Please correct me if I am wrong, I think all VSTS IDE is built on VSTS Shell, so SQL Server Management Studio as a part of VSTS IDE, should also be dependent on VSTS Shell. I do not know why SQL Server management studio are not dependent on VSTS Shell. In other words, my question is what kinds of component is dependent on VSTS Shell. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Yes. I don't see any item for VS Shell in "Program and Features" control panel. 2. I think we should separate VS Shell *technology* and *product*. SQL Server Management Studio depends on VS tech but I don't *think* it depends on VS Shell Integrated Mode as a *product*.

Comment: SSMS *does* depend on VSShell thats why it gets installed if not available, and not installed if already existing

Comment: @Wayne: I have a machine without VSTS and just SQL Server Management Studio 2008. It doesn't list VS Shell Integrated Mode in add/remove programs.

Answer (score 2):

The shell version means that applications can merge into the shell and be used independently. Isolated mode means that this version only performs one task and is a complete separate application..

See: [VS2k8 Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx2008/products/bb933751.aspx)

Comment: Are there any Microsoft tools dependent on VSTS Shell? My confusion is from this thread,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844945/sql-server-2008-installation-error

I find I have to uninstall VSTS Shell in order to install SQL Server 2008, but I do not know whether there are any tools dependent on VSTS Shell. :-(

Comment: You should not have to uninstall the shell to install SQL 2008. What you could do is run SP1 for VS2k8 and see if that resolves your issue

Answer (score 2):

A clearly defined difference is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685612%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)