# Visual studio 2008 Shell be installed in a terminal which is already having Visual Studio 2010 Shell

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, shell

Can Visual studio 2008 Shell be installed in a terminal which is already having Visual Studio 2010 Shell.VS 2010 Shell is essential to the Project. So I want VS 2008 in my terminal, without disturbing the existing VS 2010)

Question 1: If so, what do we exactly need to get it installed in my terminal.
Sorry the question might sound stupid, but I am a Java developer and I have no idea of Visual studio. Thanks in advance for your help.

Question 2: Also what does it mean by Visual Studio 2010 Shell Version? What does Shell means

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Visual Studio 2010 be installed with Visual Studio 2008 side by side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627329/can-visual-studio-2010-be-installed-with-visual-studio-2008-side-by-side)

Answer (score 0):

If by "terminal", you mean a PC running Windows, then yes, you can have two different versions of Visual Studio installed simultaneously.  I'm assuming you have the requisite licences from Microsoft.  Just run the install from the downloaded executable or the installation CD as usual.

Comment: Yes I have PC running on Windows. Thank you.

Comment: What is meant by Visual studio 2010 Shell version? What does shell mean?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845152/what-is-visual-studio-2008-shell-integrated-mode)