# Error in installation of SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Express on my machine but I can't find the Management Studio.

[image: im]

I downloaded two versions of SQL Server Management Studio, 2008 and R2

This is the result

[image: im2]

I don't know what is exactly the problem, on my machine I have VS2008, VS2010 and VS2012 express for web.

I googled about this topic and i installed the `SP1` package.

[image: im5]

I had SQL Server 2005 with its management tool and it worked very well, but now I need to change to the 2008's version, I don't know if I made an error when I uninstalled one of them.

[image: im3]

So :

1. What is the reason of this error?
2. How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Have you checked under `SQL Server 2008 R2`

Comment: @M.Ali i got exactly the same error when i tried to install SQL Server 2008 R2 management tool

Comment: Seems like a clear error message to me. Install SP 1 for Visual Studio 2008 and rerun the setup.

Comment: yes i installed the SP1 and rerun the setup ==> i got this result

Comment: follow this page for your error :

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844945/sql-server-2008-installation-error-previous-releases-of-microsoft-visual-studio>